# character # to separate url in jquery mobile site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, jquery-mobile

i don't understund the use of the url with jquery mobile. 
when i navigate in a jquery mobile site the url is strange (for me)
there are even 2 url separate by "#" character.
for example if i visit first the login page of my site and the go to the home page the url become:
`http://mysite/login#/home`

why? 
how can i fix this?

i would that che url works as the classical browser mode, if i visit the login page the url must be: `http://mysite/login`
after if i go to the home page the url must be: `http://mysite/home`

my site is write in ruby on rails 3 and i use the last version of jquery (1.7.1) and jquery mobile (1.1.0)

i won't to use the rel=external solution, the navigation became too slow

Comment: any chance you could post some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use data-ajax="false", but that would destroy the transitions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pushStatePlugin` described on [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html).